# Allow requests only from specific domains

Tags: laravel

I'm building an API with Laravel 5.

My app will be consumed from multiple apps (web, CRM, mobile, etc).

How can I allow requests from only specific domains?

I found this middleware, but I think this is not what I'm looking for: http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/

Comment: You could have a list of allowed IP address?

Comment: Yes, I have all the ips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with allow and deny rules from Nginx:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/